# Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

Tags: android, eclipse, syntax, token

I keep getting this error saying "Syntax error on token "}", delete this token." on the last line, why? I have searching for the error but I can't seem to find it. As you can see it's a service, calling on another service every once in a while.

```
package com.iggeman.updater;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class UpdaterService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = UpdaterService.class
        .getSimpleName();
private Updater updater;
public boolean isRunning = false;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    updater = new Updater();

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    if (this.isRunning == false) {
        updater.start();
        this.isRunning = true;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}

@Override
public synchronized void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    if (this.isRunning) {
        updater.interrupt();
    }

    updater = null;

    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

class Updater extends Thread {
    static final long DELAY = 10000;
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public Updater() {
        super("Updater");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
        isRunning = true;
        while (isRunning) {
            try {
                // Do something

                startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), StartServiceTwo.class));

                Log.d(TAG, "Updater running");

                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // interrupted
                isRunning = false;
            }
        } // while
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return this.isRunning();
    }
}
}
```

I have gone through all the brackets and I can't find anyone that isn't where it's supposed to be.

Edit:

Still the error:

```
package com.iggeman.updater;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class UpdaterService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = UpdaterService.class
        .getSimpleName();
private Updater updater;
public boolean isRunning = false;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    updater = new Updater();

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    if (this.isRunning == false) {
        updater.start();
        this.isRunning = true;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}

@Override
public synchronized void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    if (this.isRunning) {
        updater.interrupt();
    }

    updater = null;

    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

class Updater extends Thread {
    static final long DELAY = 10000;
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public Updater() {
        super("Updater");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
        isRunning = true;
        while (isRunning) {
            try {
                // Do something

                startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), StartServiceTwo.class));

                Log.d(TAG, "Updater running");

                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // interrupted
                isRunning = false;
            }
        } // while
    } //Run     
} //Class updater

public boolean isRunning() {
        return this.isRunning();
   }
}  //Main body
```

Comment: ...and everyone frantically posts an answer suggesting to delete the extra `}` for an easy 10 points...

Comment: Except by the looks of it as-pasted, he doesn't.  Some of the indenting doesn't do him any favors but as is in the question there's not an extra brace.

Comment: Haha Alex, I have tried that but as far as I can see there are the right amount of closing brackets.

Comment: @Eric Auto-format (or hover-match the parens) and check again.

Comment: @pst it matches the main class.  The one at the same indent level above it matches the inner class

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo Yeah, I thought the main class was closed above at first .. I blame formatting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely not an issue with your code, but Eclipse.  Restart the computer, and then re-build the project.

If that does not work, try compiling with another program.  If it works, then it's just Eclipse being weird.

Comment: You're right. I just deleted the error message, compiled again and then it worked fine!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Glad it worked.  Although, @whoever-downvoted-me, what's with the downvote? :/

Answer (score 0):

As-pasted, the error message is incorrect and you have the proper number of matching braces in the right places (though the indentation above is unforgiving).  However, barring a crazy compiler corner-case that can't match braces correctly, I'm guessing you've pasted all but that last brace that it's complaining about.  Do as the error message suggests and delete the token on the line it suggests.

Comment: I think Eclipse has freaked out. Whatever I do, even if I delete the whole code the error is still there.

Comment: Clean out the build output by running `Clean` from the `Project` menu and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your ADT plugin to version 20.0.1. This is a [known bug in ADT 20](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33985).

All the other tips for cleaning, re-creating the project and so on will not solve the issue permanently, but only for a while, until you happen to trigger the bug again.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of this error by running a `clean install` followed with `Maven -> Update Project`

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was an encoding issue or some weird invisible character because I pasted some code from Microsoft Teams.

I opened outlook (gmail, whataver), pasted the code, sent the email to myself and copied it again, then it worked fine.

I couldn't solve it using an only UITF-8 validator, and notepad++ didn't show anything weird either.