# Android SDK false syntax error "Syntax error on token "}", delete this token."

Tags: android, syntax, sdk

So I'm trying to complete Google's "My First App", and have gotten everything to work up to this point. However, I am receiving a false error on two of my brackets.

I am not allowed to post images for some reason, so here is a link to my screencap (which I thought appropriate as it highlighted all the errors): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg3CN.jpg

I have cleaned the build, rebuilt the project, restarted my computer, completely wiped the code, and repeated in all manner of orders to no avail. Someone here experienced a similar problem on an older build of the ADT plugin: [Syntax error on token "}", delete this token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570576/syntax-error-on-token-delete-this-token)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as three hours of my time and a lot of caffeine haven't made a dent in the problem.

Comment: Try to remove the extra "}" then - there is likely one-too-many. Use the IDEs "auto indent" functionality to help isolate possible brace issues. (And no, images don't "show code" well.)

Comment: The first highlighted bracket is the end of the MainActivity class, making sendMessage a method that is not part of a class.  Move the highlighted brace to where the second highlighted brace is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Android SDK false syntax error “Syntax error on token ”}“

I think its not false syntax error. You need to put the `sendMessage` function inside the `}` quote at line `29`, which is showing the error. Your function is outside the `Activity`. That is why it is giving the error since last 3 hours :).

Comment: Thank you so much; I don't have enough reputation to vote you yet. Can't believe the documentation told me to place that at the end of the file...

Comment: @user2744882 No worries. If it soled your issue, you an just accept the answer by clicking the left 'correct' mark near the answer. The documentation meant that you should place that at the `end` assuming that you'll place it inside the `Activity` itself. Everything goes inside hose last ending `}` quotes. It was just a mis-understanding.

Comment: Also, you can show the code sniplets in the question. No need to put snapshots. You are new to the site. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask would be a good read for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the screencap, your class ends on line 29, and the sendMessage method is outside the class.  Put the sendMessage method inside the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "}" from line 29 and add it to the end of the code..:)

Answer (score 0):

The class should end after send message function. All the code for the class should be within that class.

So move the } to the end of the file.