# Abstract class and concrete class constructors in Java

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class

I have this interface:

```
import fondt2.extended.PhoneCall;

public interface Rate {
    public double getCallCost(PhoneCall call);
    public String getName();
    public boolean isApplicableTo(String destinationNumber);
    public boolean isValid();
}
```

and this abstract class with his own constructor:

```
import fondt2.extended.PhoneCall;
import java.util.Arrays;

public abstract class BandsRate implements Rate {
    protected Band[] bands;
    protected int intervalInMillis;
    protected String name;
    protected String numberRoot;
    protected double startCallCost;

    public BandsRate(String name,Band[] bands, int intervalInMillis, double startCallCost, String numberRoot){
        this.name = name;
        this.intervalInMillis = intervalInMillis;
        this.startCallCost = startCallCost;
        this.numberRoot = numberRoot;
        this.bands = Arrays.copyOf(bands, bands.length);
    }
   public abstract double getCallCost(PhoneCall call);

   protected double getStartCallCost(){
        return this.startCallCost;
    }
   protected int getIntervalInMillis(){
        return this.intervalInMillis;
    }
```

Now I want to create a concrete class extending the abstract class above:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import fondt2.extended.*;

public class SimpleBandsRate extends BandsRate {

public SimpleBandsRate(String name, Band[] bands, int intervalInMillis, double startCallCost, String numberRoot){
    super(name, bands, intervalInMillis, startCallCost, numberRoot);
}
 double getCallCost(PhoneCall call){
    double costPerInterval = getCostPerInterval(call.getStart());
    if (costPerInterval == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    long difference = Duration.between(call.getStart(), call.getEnd()).toMillis();
    int intervalCount = (int) (difference / super.getIntervalInMillis());
    return (double) super.getStartCallCost() + intervalCount * costPerInterval; 
  }

}
```

The compiler shows a lot of errors: like "String cannot be resolved to a variable" , "Syntax error on token 'numberRoot' delete this token", "startCallCost cannot be resolved to a variable" etc.. What did I get wrong?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, you can follow the solution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570576/syntax-error-on-token-delete-this-token

Comment: Try using an IDE where it'll highlight the error

Comment: Have you written this code manually? Or did you copy it from some other place?

Comment: Yes.. It was Eclipse's fault.. Maybe the autorebuild function gets him crazy! I restarted and now it works! Thanks